# controller name Ember JS

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have these controllers

clusters_controller.js.coffee

`Portal.DashboardClustersController = Ember.ArrayController.extend`

dashboard_controller.js.coffee

`Portal.DashboardController = Ember.ArrayController.extend`

I have a template from which I am trying to submitting a form on action in dashboardCluster controller but I am getting following error below

``` Uncaught ReferenceError: <Portal.DashboardController:ember794>#needs does not include ``dashboard_clusters``. To access the dashboard_clusters controller from <Portal.DashboardController:ember794>, <Portal.DashboardController:ember794> should have a ``` n......o.

Form in Template

`<form role="form" {{action "createCluster" target="controllers.dashboard_clusters" on="submit"}}>`

what should be the controller name which I mention in target so my call goes to action `createCluster` in `Portal.DashboardClustersController`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to call another controller from a controller the property `needs` is required (http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/) and in this case using the value `dashboardClusters` within the `needs` property would be sufficient to call the controller named `DashboardClustersController`.
Specifically this is an example,

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qesilanu/1/edit

**js**

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route("dashboardClusters",{path:"dashboard-clusters"});
  this.route("dashboard");
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    this.transitionTo("dashboardClusters");
  }
});

App.DashboardController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs:["dashboardClusters"],
  test:function(){
    var dashboardClustersController = this.get("controllers.dashboardClusters");
      alert("From DashboardController calling DashboardClustersController:"+dashboardClustersController);
  }
});

App.DashboardClustersController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs:["dashboard"],
  actions:{
    testAction:function(){
      var dashboardController = this.get("controllers.dashboard");
      alert("From DashboardClustersController calling DashboardController:"+dashboardController);
      dashboardController.test();
    }
  }
});
```

**hbs**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{outlet}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="dashboard">
    in dashboard,<br/>
    <button {{action "testAction" target="controllers.dashboardClusters"}} >test2</button><br/>
    {{#link-to "dashboard"}}go to dashboard clusters{{/link-to}}
  </script>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="dashboardClusters">
    in dashboard clusters,<br/>
    <button {{action "testAction"}} >test1</button><br/>
    {{#link-to "dashboard"}}go to dashboard{{/link-to}}
  </script>
```